# Zoom in when hovering over image - CSS & HTML

Tags: html, css

I am making a Gallery for my site. In my site, I am going to have my pictures set out like [THIS](http://finsgraphics.com/?portfolio_category=art). But, what I want to know is how to make it zoom in when I hover over it. Not like a magnifying glass, just make the image bigger by 5 to 10%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS3 Transform as shown here:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/scale-on-hover-with-webkit-transition/

Also include the `-moz-, -o-, -webkit-, -ms-` counterparts of `transform` for browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS3 Transitions and background-size property using percentages

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp